# Beautiful Soup find_all error when cant find tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Just as the title says I need to some how check if the find_all returns a value.

First attempt. This works no issue

```
cmslink =  'https://www.cms.gov/research-statistics-data-and-systemsstatistics-trends-and-reportsmcradvpartdenroldatamonthly-pdp/pdp-enrollment-scc-2020-01'
content, _ = http_request_get(url=cmslink,payload={'t':''},parse=True)
table = [a['href'] for a in content.find("ul", class_="field__items").find_all('a')]
```

Second attempt. This attempt fails because the page does not have the link it's looking for

```
cmslink = 'https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Monthly-Contract-and-Enrollment-Summary-Report-Items/Contract-Summary-2017-04'
content, _ = http_request_get(url=cmslink,payload={'t':''},parse=True)
table = [a['href'] for a in content.find("ul", class_="field__items").find_all('a')]
```

My question is how can check some how before executing the line line that sets table variable.

Error I am getting did not help much I figured out link was missing by checking page. When I ran it on a page that didnt have link missing it ran fine.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: Two ways. 1) You can use a try, except. 2) Check if the length of the result of find_all('a') is greater than 0 before you try to get the href attribute.

Comment: Ok Sri. agreed but whats the syntax I cant run my current line as it fails. My python syntax still a work in progress

Answer (score 1):

As Sri suggests:

```
try:
    table = [a['href'] for a in content.find("ul", class_="field__items").find_all('a')]
except AttributeError:
    print( 'No class_="field__items" found')
```

or:

```
a_list = content.find("ul", class_="field__items")
if len(a_list != 0):
    table = [a['href'] for a in a_list.find_all('a')]
```

Comment: ok the first one worked thank you. The second one did not work because it failed trying to execute